# Linux initramfs read-only

Tags: linux, filesystems, kernel, read-only, initramfs

In a Linux system consisting of a bootloader, the kernel and an initramfs (no block devices, no other root filesystem):

Is it possible to make the initramfs read-only once expanded into memory?

Comment: Probably, but why?  I suspect the kernel itself doesn't care one way or the other.  But you almost certainly need to start some software after loading the kernel, and the software you start may need write access.

Answer (score 1):

You could try giving the remount option a whirl.

```
mount -o remount,ro /
```

Do pay heed to Zoredache's comment. Just because you can doesn't mean it won't go terribly, horribly wrong.